# Updating variable value after redefinition

Tags: r

A newbie question for you R folks:

Case scenario:

1. I define variable A: A=number
2. I define other variables based on A: B=number*A
3. I change the definition of A: A=different number

[Q]. How can I get R to automatically update the value of B, without redefining it again?

E.g.: 
1. A=1000; 
2. B=A/10; (B=100)
3. Changed my mind: A=1100 after all;

```
>A
1100
>B
100
```

B should be 110 (1100/10), but its value has not been updated - hence it reads 100. Without redefining B, how can I update its value?

Thanks!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck answers your question nicely below, but I suggest that you also consider changing your idiom -- while it is convenient (and similar to both spreadsheets and to symbolic math programs like Sage or Mathematica), it's un-idiomatic for R.

Comment: Agree with @Bolker, but another approach is to "replay" the previous calculations with the aid of an IDE such as emacs/ess or RStudio.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
A <- 1000
makeActiveBinding("B", function() A/10, .GlobalEnv)
B
## [1] 100
A <- 1100
B
## [1] 110
```

Answer (score 2):

You are proposing making B a function of A (and possibly of the "number" in that second expression)

```
A=10
B <- function(Number=3.5) { A*Number }
B()
# [1] 35
A <- 15
B()
# [1] 52.5
```